# AS3 - How to Flip tween

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to recreate something like the first bend flip example in this link - http://activeden.net/item/easy-flip-as3-flip-tween-class/111357

Does anyone know any tutorials or pointers for me to start?

Comment: Could just buy the package. Hell, I'll even buy it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The demo there is using http://www.greensock.com tween classes.
Basically they is doing tween on a axis, changining the axis values which causing this rotation effect.

http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

You can stack different tweens on a single object, enriching it with effects.\

check this : http://www.riacodes.com/flash/3d-rotation-with-flash-cs4/

Comment: Though everything you've said is correct, I wouldn't even know where to begin when it comes to applying 3D animation effects to an object like that.

Comment: Great tutorial, but I was looking for something that had the back view the right way around instead of reflected. do you know anything like that?